# Is it possible to enable remote jmx monitoring programmatically?

Tags: java, multiprocessing, monitoring, jmx

I need to programmatically start a new java process and dynamically set the JMX port.
So instead of doing this

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9995 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

I would like to do the following

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "127.0.0.1" );
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote", "true" );
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false" );
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false" );
System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port", "9995"  );
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: IMHO its not possible.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276881/how-to-set-jmx-remote-port-system-environment-parameters-through-java-code-for-r). You can still remotely monitor the JVM using [Java Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html) if that is your goal.

Comment: Can I have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By the time your code is called you've missed your chance to configure the jmxremote connector.

What you need to do is create your own rmi registry and a JMXConnectorServer to listen for rmi calls and pass them to the MBeanServer.

```
private void createJmxConnectorServer() throws IOException {
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1234);
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1234/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnectorServer svr = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, mbs);
    svr.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. Works very well for me.

Comment: Great to know I've helped :)

Comment: careful, this will accept any password unless you do `HashMap<String,Object> env = new HashMap<String,Object>(); env.put("jmx.remote.x.password.file", "path-to-password-file");`, and pass that in when you create the `JMXConnectorServer`, where you currently have the `null`.

Still, thanks so much for putting me on the right path!!

Comment: I've not been able to programmatically assign a JMX authenticator.  Is there a way to inject it instead of using system properties?